# SpriteKit EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on main function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I am building kind of drawing functionality for which I used this tutorial as a reference: https://www.raywenderlich.com/80586/make-line-drawing-game-sprite-kit-swift. What confuses me is that I get the error after some time playing - not on the start. These are the two functions I use for the drawing:

```
func createPathToMove() -> CGPathRef? {

    if wayPoints.count <= 1 {
        return nil
    }

    let ref = CGPathCreateMutable()

    for i in 0 ..< wayPoints.count {
        let p = wayPoints[i]

        if i == 0 {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(ref, nil, p.x, p.y)
        } else {
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, nil, p.x, p.y)
        }
    }

    return ref
}

func drawLines() {

    enumerateChildNodesWithName("line", usingBlock: {node, stop in

        node.removeFromParent()

    })


        if let path = createPathToMove() {
            let shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
            shapeNode.path = path
            shapeNode.name = "line"
            shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            shapeNode.lineWidth = 2
            shapeNode.zPosition = 1

            self.addChild(shapeNode)
        }

}
```

And here I invoke the drawLines() function:

```
func moveSprite(sprite: SKSpriteNode, velocity: CGPoint) {

    let amountToMove = CGPoint(x: velocity.x * CGFloat(dt),
                               y: velocity.y * CGFloat(dt))

    sprite.position = CGPoint(
        x: sprite.position.x + amountToMove.x,
        y: sprite.position.y + amountToMove.y)
    wayPoints.append(sprite.position)
    drawLines()
}
```

Any help will be appreciated as I couldn't find any working solutions.

Comment: can you post some more details like on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: This is the error when it's running on device:
  http://screencast.com/t/WuexAqcv

And this when on the simulator:
http://screencast.com/t/sNl7uE6MVvi